# Can't cat to temp file by mktemp on macOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: bash, macos, unix

Objective: Securely create and use a temp directory or file and write to it.

I'm having a difficult time appending some data to a heredoc file created by `mktemp` using `cat`. Is it because I'm writing to a Read-only filesystem (e.g., `/tmp/`)? Oddly, writing with `echo`  works but `cat` doesn't.

This was tested on Darwin, macOS Catalina 10.15.

For example:

```
cat > "$(mktemp /tmp/test.plist.XXXXXXXXXX)" << EOF
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
        <key>Username</key>
        <string>${currentUser}</string>
        <key>Password</key>
        <string>${currentPass}</string>
EOF
```

Example of usage:

```
➜ echo  "This is a test" >  $(mktemp -q /tmp/test.XXXXXXXXXX 2> /dev/null || echo "didn't work")
~
➜ cat /tmp/test.pVat43uXv5
This is a test
~
➜ cat "This is a test" >  $(mktemp -q /tmp/test.XXXXXXXXXX 2> /dev/null || echo "didn't work")
cat: This is a test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your two problems are: 1. Using `${..}` instead of `$()` in your here doc example, and 2. Giving `cat` a string instead of a filename in your example of usage. The difference between echo and cat is that `echo` writes a string directly, while `cat` will interpret the string as a filename to read

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for the explanation! Objectively, what I'm trying to do is to securely create a temporary file with the written xml data mentioned on example 1 using `cat` to append the information into that plist. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Your original post had two examples with two different problems as mentioned. The first example in your edited post should work fine.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yep, example 1 worked! As a follow-up, is there a reason why I can't store the `cat ` and `mktemp` to a variable using command substitution even though we were able to successfully write to the file? For example, `tmpfiile=$(cat > "$(mktemp /tmp/test.plist.XXXXXXXXXX)" << EOF...` says it's empty.

Comment: The output of mktemp is being captured and used for a redirection, and the output of cat is being written to a file. There's no output left to put in a variable.